# Is there an email list for updates?

Tags: okhttp

The company I work with is currently using this SDK. We wanted to find a way to consolidate the various SDKs we work with. We were wondering if the OkHttp has an email list we can sign up for updates such as Deprecation Schedules, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better addressed to the OkHttp development team.

Answer (score 0):

We don’t do email announcements. But there's a few things you can track instead, and potentially track via email.

We post all releases to our [changelog](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) file. We also tag releases, and GitHub exposes this in it's [Releases UI](https://github.com/square/okhttp/releases). You can watch releases via GitHub also.